# PHP don't update time

Tags: php, date

I made php code to add something like posts on side and above is time of adding it but only first post are getting updated time but next posts have time of first one (first are getting 16:35 and next have 16:35 also) here is code of data.php

```
session_start();
$dzien = date("d");
$mies = date ("m");
$rok = date("Y");
$_SESSION['data'] = $dzien.".".$mies.".".$rok;
$godz = date("G");
$min = date("i");
$_SESSION['czas'] = $godz.":".$min; 
header("Location: edit.php");
exit();
```

And here is file.php which add posts and time:

```
session_start();
header("Location: data.php");
$tekst ="<div class='wpis'><div class='data' ><p class='tdata'>".$_SESSION['data']." ".$_SESSION['czas']."</p></div><div class='klaska'>". $_POST['pole']."</div></div>";
$fp = fopen("inne.txt", "r");
$stare = fread($fp,filesize("inne.txt"));
fclose($fp);
$ntekst = $tekst.$stare;
$fp = fopen("inne.txt", "w");
fputs($fp,$ntekst);
fclose($fp);
header("Location: index.php");
exit();
```

I want to get in next posts updated time of add

Comment: When you save the time in a session it will 'freeze' so you need to have a date() in session OR maybe use  SQL's NOW()

Answer (score 0):

Line 2 of file.php prepares a header to redirect to data.php, but at the end of the file you prepare another header to redirect to index.php. See comment by shutout2730 at yahoo dot com in [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):
Likely the first redirect is replaced by the later one and hence does nothing. There appear to be exceptions based on output echo, print and buffering.
Are you running data.php from someplace else to initialise it?
I suspect data.php is not called as you expect and hence session is not being updated.